# count(*) and select is giving different result

Tags: hive

`SELECT COUNT(*) from customer_tbl` is giving `8000` as count.
If I do `SELECT * from customer_tbl` is returning only `2` records.
I have gathered the stats on the table still same problem.
Could you please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `select count(*)` is **broken by design**. Don't ask me why. It's fast and wrong -- hurrah, it's fast! Try to force Hive to spawn an actual Yarn job e.g. `select count(*) from XYZ where ID is not null` where you know that ID cannot be null in that table...

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080276/wrong-result-for-count-in-hive-table. Does the answers in the other post help?